# Javascript strange variable var x = (x, y == "z");

Tags: javascript, scope, var

```
var win=(win,feedback[i]["final"] =="win");
```

Hi guys im using an assessment engine called engage heres the tut im following http://146.191.107.189/documentation/tutorial

however there is a line in it you can see above and i have no idea what its supposed to do. it would be good to mention that the win variable is not defined anywhere else in the code.

Comment: `win` is defined with the `var win` which is hoisted to the beginning of the scope. Beside that `win` will become the result of the equation. But that construct does not make sense to me.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but it seems that it just becomes the result of `feedback[i]["final"] =="win"`.

Comment: so if feedback[i]["final"] is equal to "win" then is would be true?

Comment: Yes it should be completly equal to `var win=(fedback[i]["final"] =="win");` so I don't know why it is written that way, maybe the code is autogenerated.

Comment: It is identical to `var win = feedback[i]["final"] == "win";` indeed

Comment: @user3454070 It's accually just depent on the last item, [it will be the last iteme as it's defined by the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: Thanks guys, doesnt really help me right now but aleast the problem isnt on my end. i dont think XD

Comment: The `win` is defined right in the your line. Thanks to the variables hoisting, `var x = (x, y)` would effectively become `var x; x = (x, y)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the effect of Javascripts [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the **last operand**.

So `win` would by the value of `feedback[i]["final"] == "win"`, being either `true` or `false`. For example:

```
var x = (1,2,3); // x => 3
```

Statement by statment here is what is happening:

```
var win = (                          // declared a variable named 'win'
    win,                             // the value of win is undefined (as it's declared by var)
    feedback[i]["final"] =="win"     // return this value, assign it to 'win'
);
```

Functionally it does the same thing as:

```
var win = ( fedback[i]["final"] == "win" );
```

---

In this case in terms of functionality doing `var x = (x, y == z)` gives no real advantages compared to doing `var x = (y == z)`. Doing the first operation would be like doing:

```
var x;
x;                          
x = (y == z);
```

Comment: But there is no real reason to have the `win, ` part at all. Or is there a situation where the existence of `win, ` would matter?

Comment: @t.niese No there really isn't any reason to have it, unless it was on the end and `win` was defined somewhere else. Otherwise it would be better to use statements which apply some operation such as `var x = (i++,i++,i)`